# How to reset a list

Tags: javascript, jquery

It might be a silly question but still i am facing problem with this.

```
  var eformDetailIds = []; 


eformDetailIds=$("[name=eform_id]").map(function(){ return $(this).val() }).get();
```

this is the code that i have written in js function and calling this function on button click.

But the problem is the list eformDetailIds containing the previous values also. could you please how to set this empty list for every function call? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry..I have to get a fresh list every time calling this function. this what i am looking for.

Comment: That code you have will return fresh array with all the values currently written in all form elements having the name `eform_id` - explain what you want instead and we'll try to guide you there.

Comment: If it helps, [here is](http://jsfiddle.net/7pdh4/) live test case  so feel free to change it and use it to demonstrate what is your goal..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the length to zero:

```
eformDetailIds.length = 0;
```

Or allocate a new array:

```
eformDetailIds = [];
```

Now, that said, according to the code you posted the entire array will definitely be replaced each time that ".map()" call runs.  In other words, the previous values will **not** remain in the array. Perhaps you should post more to explain what it is that makes you think the old values remain.

Comment: But i already used the second option var eformDetailIds = []; but still not working. please suggest me

Comment: @Satya you have not posted enough information to know what the problem is.  When you completely re-assign the value like that, previous values **will not remain in the array**; in fact it's an entirely **new** array.

Comment: Hi Pointy..The answer you provided me is correct and should work. But i found the problem is not with this. thank you somuch

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget you can always reset the array in this way:

```
myArray = new Array();
```

It is pretty easy.

Comment: This answer is a true statement, but note that `x = []` and `x = new Array()` are exactly the same.